# Indent LaTeX code NOT in an environment using latexindent

Tags: latexindent

I really like how [`latexindent`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) does a good job indenting most parts of my code in a document. However, there are a few instances where `latexindent` doesn't do what I want it to do.

These instances generally involve codes that I'd like to be indented, but are not wrapped within an environment/braces/brackets. So they end up being ignored due to lack of "identifiers", so to speak.

The following examples illustrate my problem. In the first two, stuff in `<...>` are **not** indented by `latexindent`. In the third one, the content of the matrix as a whole will be indented (since they are wrapped by `{}`), but `&` and `\\` are not necessarily aligned (but they would be if this were in an `array` environment).

- LaTeX conditional statements

  ```
  \if
    <...>
  \else
    <...>
  \fi
  ```
- TikZ path that spans several lines. For example, `latexindent` doesn't produce the following indentation:

  ```
  \path 
    <some complicated operations>
  ;
  ```
- Alignment of `&` and `\\` in TikZ `\matrix` command:

  ```
  \matrix[matrix of nodes]{
    looooong cell & looooong cell \\
    short cell    & short cell    \\
  };
  ```

So my question is: Is there a way to configure the `.yaml` file to deal with the above issues.

Comment: *As the author* Thanks for trying `latexindent`, it's nice to have the support :) Bullets 1 and 3 are at the very top of my to do list- it's nice that someone thought of them independently :) Bullet 2 sounds tricky, but it would be a good challenge. I'll continue to develop the script, and post back with updates. For the moment, the answer is essentially: 'no, but I'm working on it :)'

Comment: @cmhughes: Thank *you* for such a great script! I hope this question won't remain unanswered for long `;)`

Comment: I'm currently working with the TL folks to iron out a few kinks- once that's sorted, I'll move on to the to do list :)

Comment: @cmhughes: And I'll be patiently waiting `:)` Good luck with the TL people!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest version of `latexindent.pl` is available on [github](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl); once I've done some more testing, I'll release it to `ctan`. This latest version addresses your question, and some more things, too- let's go through them one by one (all of this is also covered in the documentation).

## `if-else-fi` constructs

These can be controlled by using the `constructIfElseFi` field- any commands found within this field will make `latexindent.pl` look for `\else` and `\fi` commands.

```
constructIfElseFi:
     ifnum: 1
     ifodd: 1
```

You can, of course, add any other commands to this (I'll update `defaultSettings.yaml` with a more comprehensive list later today)

*Sample before*

```
\ifnum\radius>5
\ifnum\radius<16
\draw[decorate,...
\fi
\fi
```

*Sample after*

```
\ifnum\radius>5
    \ifnum\radius<16
        \draw[decorate,...
    \fi
\fi
```

## `tikz paths spanning several lines`

The new version of `latexindent.pl` contains switches to add indentation after `\item` commands

```
indentAfterItems:
    itemize: 1
    enumerate: 1
    list: 1
```

and you can have any `item` names you like specified in

```
itemNames:
    item: 1
    myitem: 1
```

As such, you can trick `latexindent.pl` into thinking that the `tikzpicture` environment has `item` commands called `path`, `node`, `draw`, and anything else by using (for example) the following code in one of your `mysettings.yaml` files:

```
indentAfterItems:
   tikzpicture: 1
itemNames:
    path: 1
    node: 0
    draw: 1
```

*Sample before*

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
<some complicated operations>
;
\node bunch of other code
<some complicated operations>
<some complicated operations>
\draw bunch of other code
<some complicated operations>
<some complicated operations>
\end{tikzpicture}
```

*Sample after*

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
        <some complicated operations>
        ;
        \node bunch of other code
        <some complicated operations>
        <some complicated operations>
    \draw bunch of other code
        <some complicated operations>
        <some complicated operations>
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that, because I had the `node` set to `0`, `latexindent.pl` does *not* treat it like an `item` command- switch it to `1`, and you obtain the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
        <some complicated operations>
        ;
    \node bunch of other code
        <some complicated operations>
        <some complicated operations>
    \draw bunch of other code
        <some complicated operations>
        <some complicated operations>
\end{tikzpicture}
```

## Alignment outside of environments

The 'brace matching' routine and the 'alignment' routine are pretty robust, but I don't want to make them fight for control- as such, to answer your last request I have added support for the following mark-up

```
\matrix{%
%* \begin{tabular}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 &   & 6 &   \\
%* \end{tabular}
}
```

You can use `%*` followed by as many spaces as you like (possibly none) together with any environment that you have specified in `lookForAlignDelims`. I appreciate that this solution isn't ideal, as it requires a bit of additional mark-up, but the alternative (a fight between brace matching and alignment) scares me.

Comment: works fine, unless chktex tells you that your "command terminated with space" and you "fix" it with an explicit `{}`, which breaks latexindent. Compare `\newif\ifsomething{}
\ifsomething{}
Writing Something
\fi`

Comment: Feel free to report questions/issues to the repository github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl

Comment: This answer needs updating....